# How to see each swap in a bubble sort (I figured it out!)

Tags: swap, bubble-sort

```
import java.util.*;

public class Zhangbubble
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int Bub[] = new int[6];
        Random randy = new Random();
        boolean Done = false;
        for (int x=0; x<6; x++)
        {
            Bub[x] = randy.nextInt(100);
            System.out.println (Bub[x]);
        }
        System.out.println ("This is the original array");
        while (! Done)
        {
            Done = true;
            for(int x = 0; x < Bub.length - 1; x++) 
            {
                for(int j = x + 1; j < Bub.length; j++)
                {
                    if(Bub[x] >Bub[j]) 
                    {
                        int temp = Bub[x];
                        Bub[x] = Bub[j];
                        Bub[j] = temp;

                    }
                }

            }
            for(int x = 0; x < Bub.length; x++) 
            {
                System.out.println(Bub[x]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

So my Bubble sort works just fine.  At least I think it does.  But I would like to see each swap and I'm not sure how to code that.  So instead of printing out just the original numbers and the ordered numbers, is there a way I can see all the number orders in between?So after looking at the number orders before the final ordered sequence, I discovered that the numbers weren't switching the way they are suppose to.  It doesn't take the first two numbers, swap them if need be, then move on the the second pair.  Instead it seems to jump around but still gives the correct ordered pair in the end.  Can someone figure out what's causing that?

Comment: Just attach debugger and monitor the variables/array. To `print` the "swap state in-between" you'll need to print *inside* the actual sort loops (i.e. where the swap occurs).

Comment: alright, I added   for(int xe = 0; xe<6; xe++)
                        {
                            System.out.print(Bub[xe]+" ");
                        }

Comment: but it gives me the numbers in a long horizontal chain, is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this...?

```
if(Bub[x] >Bub[j]) 
{
    System.out.println("Swapping value "+Bub[x]+" at index "+x);
    System.out.println("    with value "+Bub[j]+" at index "+j);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do your printing in this way :

```
System.out.print("[");
 for(int xe = 0; xe<6; xe++) { System.out.print(Bub[xe]+" "); 
System.out.println("]");
```

but I still recommend you to use Debugger to do that. Then you can see the changes of all the variables in your code line by line.